# Is Brawl a keeper against Priests?

Tags: hearthstone

I don't play Warrior decks, so I don't know the usual strategies. If a Warrior is playing a typical control deck, like this #1 Legend deck:

https://www.hearthstonetopdecks.com/decks/control-warrior-1-legend-jarla-uldum-post-nerf/

will they normally keep Brawl in the mulligan when playing against a Priest?

Comment: I would think they wouldn't.  Priest decks currently in the Meta don't go very wide on the board, at least not in the early stages of a game